# MS Access DB front end SQL Server Back End Unable to Open any form as New Record after table migration

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have similar issue to one previously posted but none of the answers helped.
I cannot open any form in my DB to a new record.
This all worked before moving tables from Access DB to SQL Server and linking back to them.

All tables have an ID column of datatype integer set as primary key on the server.
All tables have a RowVersion column of datatype datestamp.
All forms are based on a single table as record source.
All columns of datatype = bit have default value set to 0 on the SQL Server.
In Access form, properties are set to allow additions = yes, allow edits = yes, I also set data entry = yes as well which wasn't necessary before SQL server hosted the tables but it didn't help anyway.
I tried on button click event that opens the form:
`Private Sub OpenFormNameBtn_Click()`
`DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", , , "[CustID]=" & Me![CustID] & " AND [EnvID]= '" & Me![EnvID] & "'"`
`Forms!DeploymentsF.Form.AllowAdditions = False`
`Forms!DeploymentsF.Form.AllowAdditions = True`
`DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`
`End Sub`
NOTE:  the criteria of custid and envId worked when the tables were in access and I need them to stay this way.

The above caused the auto number ID to appear on the form for an instant but then it disappeared just as quickly!  In the code behind the submit button at the bottom of the form (to write the record to the table), it errors out and I see where the Form's ID field = Null in debug so it couldn't write the id in the update statement to the table. I CAN, however, insert a record into the table with a query insert statement on the SQL server no problem  AND I can edit records in forms and sub forms and it writes to the tables on the SQL Server.

I also tried a simple form with no criteria and no pre-filling and got the error, "Can't go to the specified record"

I tried button click event:  DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", , , , acFormAdd.

Anyone seen this before and have a solution? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you open a linked SQL table directly in Access and add a new record?

Comment: On the more complicated form's table that has the disappearing Auto number ID on the form, yes!  It shows New on the bottom row of the table, I keyed in a record and it saved.  On the simple table, NO.  It has no new row at the bottom.

Comment: Can you open a linked SQL table directly? Can you edit those? Can you add records when opening a linked table? It makes ZERO sense to go try complex code, and all kinds of fancy things like using forms until you test and check if you can edit linked tables, and also add records in a linked table. So, can you open a linked SQL table directly?

Comment: you might have used a SQLServer datatype not supported by MsAccess. Share the table structure for a simple table not allowing inserts.

Comment: Again, everything worked until I moved the tables to the SQL Server.   Yes, I was able to edit and add records in access directly and on the sql server.  I re-linked all of the tables and it may be working now, although I have found other errors that weren't there before so I haven't been able to test all of the way through.  I'll keep plugging away at it.

Comment: The first simple test BEFORE trying forms etc, is to open a linked table to sql server in access. Can you edit rows, and can you add rows by opening that linked table. If you can edit rows, and add rows when opening a linked table in access, then the form(s) in question should for the most part also work. But, if you can't open the linked tables, and edit linked tables, and add rows to a linked table? Then trying forms is too soon - you have to resolve and ensure that a simple linked table allows editing and adding of rows. Once you tested and checked if table editing works, then try form

Comment: This is resolved.  I have code in the Main Menu form load event that relinks the tables every time I open it.  For some reason, the link had gotten stale.  I closed and opened the DB and when the tables re-linked it was fixed.  Thanks for your help.